# How to execute a method after the execution of another method in Flutter(Dart)

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, dart

I want to execute a method after the successful execution of another method. How can I do it? Please tell me with example.

Comment: what does this method return, a future ?

Comment: is the first method you're trying to execute asynchronous? try using try or await ... .then()

Comment: all of my methods are simply void methods. But I want these methods to execute asynchronously. Please give me an example of two methods with asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your method `Asynchronous`

you can use `futures`, `async`, `await`

Try this way

> Make your first method  `async` method like below example

```
Future<int> methodOne() async {
    debugPrint('first method called');
    sleep(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    return 4;

  }
  methodTwo() {
    debugPrint('second method called');
  }
```

now you can call your methods like this

```
          GestureDetector(
              onTap: () async {
                await methodOne().then((value) {
                  methodTwo();
                });
              },
              child: Center(child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Text("Click Me"),
              ))),
```

For more information please read [Asynchronous programming in flutter](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#:%7E:text=An%20async%20function%20runs%20synchronously,within%20the%20async%20function%20body.)

Comment: What is "value" inside "then((value){})" ?

Comment: @SantoShakil it is the `value` which you have return from `methodOne()`